# string.Format does not append the given args

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I'm writing an extension for string.Format (which I've done before with no problems.)

My extension:

```
    public static string FormatWith(this string source, params object[] args) {
        source.ThrowIfNull("source");

        return string.Format(source, args);
    }
```

My test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void FormatWith_ShouldReturnCorrectResult_FromValidArgs() {
        var expected = "testing 123";
        var actual = "test".FormatWith("ing", " ", 123);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

In my test, after the call to FormatWith, actual should be "testing 123" but it is just "test".

My test's message:

```
    Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<testing123>. Actual:<test>.
```

I've tried passing types other than string into the extension but the result is unchanged. And I'm sure source.ThrowIfNull is not throwing an exception.

So what gives? Am I overlooking something? A nice answer would show me a working implementation of FormatWith along with an explanation of why my implementation is not working.

Edit: I'm an idiot and completely forgot about {0}, {1}... I use this on a daily basis too. Will accept first answer when timer is up. Thanks guys.

Comment: `String.Format` needs markers, such as `{0}` in it's format string. It looks like you just want to append, so use `+` or perhaps `Join`. Oh, [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.string.format(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=hoX-UuvsLIqa2AW5g4DQBA&usg=AFQjCNGVlOAX1XvVPeQrzDqOQ4KNQMZ1AA&sig2=cYA7yJvLsfAoo8smw3D0gA&bvm=bv.61535280,d.b2I)

Comment: As an aside, why bother with an extension method? Why not just use String.Format() as it was intended? String.Format("test{0} {1}", "ing", "123")?

Comment: I prefer the syntax of the extension. strSomething.FormatWith(1, 2) is prettier than string.Format(strSomething, 1, 2) to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not a .NET guy, but I can read API docs: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

If I'm not mistaken, your source string needs to explicitly add your arguments to the string.

```
var actual = "test{0}{1}{2}".FormatWith("ing", " ", 123);
```

Feel free to correct me .NET folks.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `String.Concat`. `String.Format` doesn't work like that.Only if you specify arguments like this:

```
string.Format("{0}, {1} ....",source,args);
```

Which you can not because you don't know the number of arguments.So you can use [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modify your usage of the function as some other others suggested, here's an implementation of FormatWith that will work as you intended it:

```
public static string FormatWith(this string source, params object[] args)
{
    var arguments = new List<object> {source};
    arguments.AddRange(args);

    return String.Concat(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Luckily nothing uses my extension yet so I'm able to use string.format correctly. Thanks for the other option though.

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote. But looking at this again, your implementation wouldn't work the same as format, which is what I actually wanted. In your defense, the question does make it look like I was trying to concatenate instead of format.

Comment: @Scott that was my -1, no harm intended.  It's difficult to accurately guess someone's intention from their erroneous code, and that seemed to be the case with your answer -- it wasn't what Smith.h.Neil was actually trying to accomplish.  A logically correct way to do the wrong thing does not answer the question, that's all.